# Geometric equivalent of the degree zero divisor class group of an algebraic function field (in the singular case)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, function-fields

In an algebraic function field $F/k$ we have the degree zero divisor class group $\text{Cl}^0(F/k)$. Now since any such function field corresponds to the function field of a normal projective curve over $k$ (in particular regular, Noetherian), it seems to me quite reasonable to ask about the corresponding object in this geometric case. How does it look like, is it simply the same, only dealing with cartier divisors?

And further: Does anything change if we don't start with the function field but with a $\underline{\text{non-regular}}$ integral and complete (projective) curve over $k$?

Comment: What is your definition of $Cl^0(F/k)$?

Comment: @Mohan It's $\text{Div}^0(F)/\text{Princ}(F)$ where $\text{Div}^0(F)$ denotes the group of degree zero divisors of $F $ and $\text{Princ}(F)$ denotes the subgroup of principal divisors. A divisor is a formal sum of places of $F/k $ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, almost all zero. The degree of a divisor is the sum over all degrees of the appearing places times the respective non-zero coefficient. This definitions are the standard ones of Stichtenoth, Algebraic Function fields and Codes.

Comment: What is $X$? A non-singular smooth projective model of $F$?

Comment: @Mohan I'm sorry, I meant $F$ in the arguments of $\text{Div}^0(\cdot), \text{Princ}(\cdot)$

Comment: These concepts are then the same, since the places of a function field are just closed points of the corresponding non-singular curve. A lot of things will go wrong if you do not take the non-singular model. For example (assume $k$ is algebraically closed), the group you have will always be an abelian variety, but for a singular curve, the corresponding group (coming from Cartier divisors) will not be.

Comment: @Mohan Can you precisely describe how the _corresponding_ group of the singular curve will look like? You don't have to describe what Cartier divisors are. I would like to see how it looks like to understand why it's not an abelian variety (are you talking about the Jacobian?) anymore for example.

Comment: For example, if $F=k(t)$, the non-singular model is $\mathbb{P}^1$ and your group is zero. But, you may take a singular model, say a plane cubic curve with a cusp. Then your group is $\mathbb{G}_a$, the additive group of $k$ and if it is a cubic curve with a node, your group is $\mathbb{G}_m$, the multiplicative group of $k$.

Comment: @Mohan And if you start with a singular curve, is there some kind of _divisor class group (of degree zero)_? Maybe the Picard group (invertible sheaves together with the tensor product) or (if the curve/scheme is integral, since they are then isomorphic) the group of Cartier divisor classes? Could one think of these groups as the generalizations of the divisor class group of the regular curve case? For instance if we consider those groups on a regular curve, would they _coincide with/correspond to_ the divisor class group of the corresponding function field?

Comment: There is a well established relation between Picard group of singular curves and its normalization, which is the regular model. Probably, you should start with the basics which can be found in say, Milnor's K-theory book.